# Save the Eggs! - An Angry Birds Puzzle (Part 1)

Tags: cipher, story, knowledge

You’re going on a fictional world tour. YAY!!!

Your first destination is the world of Angry Birds.

---

**Sub-part 1**

When you reach Bird Town, all the birds have a party to celebrate the arrival of the greatest puzzler in the world. But during the party, those sneaky pigs stole the birds eggs! You decide to help the birds and go with some of them to Pig City.

Remembering the [last](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Angry_Birds_Movie#Plot) time the pigs did this, your team brings down the king’s palace (literally) but don’t find anything. Except a letter just above the fireplace…

> Your Oinkness, we have secured the eggs. Remembering the last time we tried this we have hidden it in an underground vault. We would have written the location directly had those birds not been so darn good at intercepting these letters. So the location is:
>
> Pbyhza = Ybpngvba bs Zvyyvjnlf
>
> Ebj = Sebqb’f ntr va ortvaavat bs SbgE - (Ab.bs lrnef orgjrra Rcvfbqrf IV : EbgW naq IVV : GSN + Zhygvcyvpngvir Vqragvgl)
>
> Just remember Your Oinkness, Theodor is the key to your success

You think a bit and then say,”I know where the eggs are!” You take out a map of Pig City…

[image: ![enter image description here]

…point to a square and say,”The eggs are there!”

**Where are the eggs?**

---

**Sub-part 2**

You go to [redacted], demolish the house standing over it, find a trapdoor and go underground. In front is a steel door with a keypad next to it. You go to the keypad and are wondering what the password is when you see a checkbox marked ‘I am the king’. You tap it and a hologram comes out with something written on it.

> Moi Vxzb’l zowq qfevyf
>
> Zvrm’z lwgrvg prglrv
>
> Moi hkwiw alwur fy &
>
> Umhuwt hemrh
>
> (Smbs Hf. Scid Jlcs (we Mvc Gwcir) - t)

You read what’s written, think a bit and then you get it! You quickly type in the password and the door opens. Inside are all the residents’ eggs! You’ve done it!

**What’s the password?**

---

You take all the eggs carefully and before you leave, you decimate Pig City. When you get back the birds host a party in your honour (again).

---

No knowledge of Angry Birds is required to solve this puzzle.

Also I’m inexperienced in puzzle making, so this might be easy [*Read*: The pigs are stupid].

---

[➡️ Angry Birds 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57960/save-the-eggs-an-angry-birds-puzzle-part-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding to Beastly's/postmortes' answers, we have:

Part 1:

> A rot13 encryption, giving
>
> ```
> Column = Location of Milliways
> Row = Frodo’s age in beginning of FotR - (No.of years between Episodes VI : RotJ and VII : TFA + Multiplicative Identity)
> ```
>
> End of the Universe (HHGTTG) = E
> 33-(2015-1983)+1 = 2
> Thus, the field is E2. While my ego urges me to say that I found the numbers on my own, Beastly's/postmortes' answers were earlier so you definitely should upvote that answer as well.

Part 2:

> is a vigenere cipher with key theodor (as given in the first part). This gives:
>
> ```
> The Hulk’s skin colour
>
> What’s hidden inside
>
> The third third of &
>
> Nitric oxide
>
> (Evil Dr. Pork Chop (in Toy Story) - m)
> ```
>
> To which the answers are:
> *Green*
> *eggs* (what's hidden inside the vault, I presume)
> *and* (&=ampersand, amp - ers - and)
> *NO*
> *ham* (Dr. Pork Chop = Hamm, minus the last m).

So the answer is:

> Green eggs and NO ham, which is a reference to a [children's book by Dr. Seuss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Eggs_and_Ham)

Answer (score 4):

Partial:

Sub Part 1 decodes as

> A Caesar shift with key 13 (Theodore Roosevelt):
>
>  Column = Location of Milliways Row = Frodo’s age in beginning of FotR - (No.of years between Episodes VI : RotJ and VII : TFA + Multiplicative Identity)

As post-mortes points out,

> Milliwayd Row is at the ‘End of the Universe’ and the end of the universe is E.

Frodo’s age is

> 33 years (his coming of age)

And there are

> 30 years between the films (in-universe), and the multiplicative number is 1.

So

> 33-(30+1) gives 2.

So the square is

> E2

Lolgast solved the second part:

With a Vigenere key of ‘Theodor’:

> The Hulk’s skin colour
> What’s hidden inside
> The third third of &
> Nitric oxide
> (Evil Dr. Pork Chop (in Toy Story)  - m)

Giving

> Green eggs and no ham

Comment: FOTR = Fellowship of the Ring, is the first book of the three of Lord of the Rings, if it helps.

Comment: By no. of years between Episode VI & VII, I meant in-universe.

Comment: @NapoleonofPuzzling so is E2 incorrect? I get the same answer if the years between is 30

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil E2 is correct.